# Handle Room transaction with completable operations

Tags: transactions, reactive

Completable inside room transaction

I need to put into a room transaction a chain of completable querys and if someone fails then rollback

```
db.runInTransaction {
 db.select().subscribe{
   dao.delete()
   .andThen(dao.delete2())
   .andThen(dao.delete2())
 }
}
```

I neet to complete transaction only if all of completable are completed